# php preg_split explode by new line

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$string = '   
1

2

3

4';

$tags = preg_split('/[;:, \rn]+/', $string); 
foreach ($tags as $to_x)
{
  echo strlen($to_x)."</br>";
}
?>
```

### Out put is wrong

explode it by new line but not displaying correct strlen .

output

```
1

2

2

2
```

actual out should be

```
1

1

1

1
```

where i am wrong???

Comment: Are u sure u need this out put? Just making sure no typo

Comment: actually i want to ask where i am wrong . why it works on $to_x[0] only . and not on all other array values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'/[;:, \r\n]+/'

Make sure it's \n